# How to make search on Time in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, search, datetime

I have two columns in table Start time and end time. I want to make search on the basis of time. I have saved the start time and end time in below format

```
14:57:44
```

using `Convert(varchar(20),Getdate(),108)`

Please help me.

Comment: You really should consider learning a little bit about the language before using it.  Date comparisons in SQL are extremely basic.

Comment: Sir if Your basic are clear then why you are not provide me the answer.

Comment: Because this is too basic to be a SO question.  This is easily solved by looking at any entry level SQL reference or tutorial.  The question could be rephrased "how do I do anything in SQL?"

Comment: Sir i am new to Sql server so i am asking here. if you dont know the answer then its k let others to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from your_table
where cast(time_column as time) between '10:00:00' and '11:00:00'
```